# HTTPie can't find JSON file when testing POST

Tags: json, post, httpie

I am having trouble test the post functionality of my REST Java app via HTTPie.  My syntax is "localhost:8080/coffees < coffee.json"  I have coffee.json in the same package/folder as my code but HTTPie is giving me a 404 File not found error.

I have tried putting the file in different locations and researched this issue for over an hour and don't  know how to to fix it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.